# How can I split output from the tf.data.Dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow, dataset, double

I have some .npy data whose shapes are [150~180, 480~512, 480~512], extracted from MRI image.

So I used some functions to refine the dataset and convert them as tf.data.Dataset type

```
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((list_image,list_label))
train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(NUM_TRN)
train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(NUM_BATCH_NPY)
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(
    lambda x,y: tf.py_function(load_dataset, inp=[x,y], Tout=[tf.float16, tf.float16]))


description:
1) list_image & list_label is the lists of .npys
---- [000_image.npy,..., 099_image.npy], [000_label.npy,.,.., 099_label.npy]

2) NUM_TRN is the number of total dataset, and it is used to shuffle all dataset
---- 100 (The number of *_image.npy)

3) NUM_BATCH_NPY is the number of .npys that will be extracted simultaneously
---- If NUM_BATCH_NPY is 3, three sets of .npys will be extracted
---- [000_image/label.npy], [001_image/label.npy], [002_image/label.npy]

4) The function 'load_dataset' will extract arrays from the .npys,
   refine the extracted .npys and stack them along 0-axis.
---- 000_image.npy->(170,360,360,1), 000_label.npy->(170,)
---- 001_image.npy->(150,360,360,1), 001_label.npy->(150,)
---- 002_image.npy->(163,360,360,1), 002_label.npy->(163,)
---- output shape of the dataset will be ((483,360,360,1),(483,))
```

As mentioned above, the arrays will be extracted per image. The questions is, how can I split this extracted dataset-type object into NUM_TRAIN_BATCH=128 slices?

**---- extracted dataset (483,360,360,1)->(128,:),(128,:), ...**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would extract batches and create new datasets:

```
datasets = []
train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(NUM_TRAIN_BATCH)
for set in train_dataset:
  set = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(set)
  datasets.append(set)
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I just tried your solution, but the lack of memory caused the kernel died. Is there better way to load some of my data and extract some slices from the loaded data?

Comment: @jisoohong try to set NUM_TRAIN_BATCH=1

Comment: Thank you, Andrey. I've changed my script as below.
`for c_epoch in range(NUM_EPOCH):
    for i, c_dataset in enumerate(train_dataset):
        b_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(c_dataset)
        b_dataset = b_dataset.shuffle(NUM_BATCH_TRN*8)
        b_dataset = b_dataset.batch(NUM_BATCH_TRN)
        model_a.fit(b_dataset)`
Sorry for the complex comment.. I'm not familiar with stackoverflow's comment formatting.